# Export environment variables inside docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

I am trying to run a shell script `env_var.sh` inside the docker container. The contents of the script is shown below. What its essentially trying is getting the access keys from a specific profile

```
echo "# Environment for AWS profile dev"

echo export AWS_PROFILE=dev
echo export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=(aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile dev)
echo export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=(aws configure get aws_secret_access_key --profile dev)
echo export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=(aws configure get region --profile dev)

echo "dev environment variables exported"
```

and this is my dockerfile

```
FROM docker:17.04.0-ce

RUN apk update && apk add python && apk add py-pip && apk add bash

RUN pip install pip --upgrade && pip install setuptools --upgrade && pip install awscli && pip install cfdeployment==0.2.3 --extra-index-url https://dn2h7gel4xith.cloudfront.net

VOLUME /tmp/work
VOLUME /root/.aws

ADD test.sh /root/test.sh
ADD aws_env.sh /root/env_var.sh
ADD config /root/.aws/config
ADD credentials /root/.aws/credentials

RUN /root/env_var.sh


ENTRYPOINT ["/root/test.sh", "cfdeployment"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

The output for `RUN /root/env_var.sh`I am seeing is as below. I don't see access key substituted from the role. Any idea what might be happening

```
Step 9/11 : RUN /root/aws_env.sh
 ---> Running in ca46f4c516eb
# Environment for AWS profile ''
export AWS_PROFILE=dev
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=

dev environment variables exported
```

or is there a different way to set these env variables which picks up the keys from from he profile  using `docker run` command?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, I think the reason env_var.sh isn't working is because it's missing dollar signs, `$( )` ... should be like this:

```
echo export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile dev)
```

But regardless of that, the better way to supply environment variables to docker containers is at run time, not baking them into the image. This way the image is de-coupled from configuration... you can change the environment variables w/out re-building, and you can remove all that mess in the Dockerfile where you're copying your local aws configuration into the image. So you would use the `docker run -e` option:

```
docker run -e AWS_PROFILE=dev -e "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile dev)" my-image
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ENV` in your **dockerfile** to create these variables, setting them individually, e.g.:

```
ENV AWS_PROFILE=dev
```

There is another command called `ARG`, which you can use to `set variables` that need to be available only on build stage.